# Is there any way to change layer's style based sql query (carto.js v4)?

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, cartodb

I'm showing a layer over a google map and I wanna change layer's style.

I have a select control that contains dataset's columns, so when the user selects an option I'm getting to carto the unique values column.

So these values I wanna take and assign them a color and apply it to the layer.

Here is a sample that I want to.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are looking for the [`setContent`](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/reference/#cartostylecartocsssetcontent) method for your Style. You have an example of editing CartoCSS [here](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-edit-sql-and-cartocss) and also [here](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-change-the-style).